# How to tokenize from a String of numbers to an int array

Tags: java, regex, tokenize

I have a String of this kind

```
String s=1956;
```

and want to convert this `String` in `int[]` array

```
[1,9,5,6];
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
int[] digits = new int[s.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; ++i) {
    digits[i] = s.charAt(i)-'0';
}
```

I could never bring myself to use `Integer.parseInt(String)` just to translate a digit character into an integer.

Comment: thank you, could you tell me the purpose of `-'0'` ?

Comment: @AndreaF The numerical characters are sequential. For instance, the character `'5'` is five places above the character `'0'`. So subtracting `'0'` from the character `'5'` gives the number `5`, which is what you want to store. That's how you translate a digit character to the integer value of that digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split` method of `String` to convert it to a `String[]`, and then you can iterate over it calling `Integer.parseInt` to populate a `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be

```
char[] nums = s.toCharArray();
int[] parsed = new int[nums.length];
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i){
    parsed[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(nums[i]));
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeah I guessed that that method existed without having to convert back to a string. I was wrong...I think the split method is more efficient. I didn't realize you could split on nothing.

Comment: thanks, nice solution... and using a Tokenizer or regular expressions??

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide a the most possible simple solution to this;

```
String s = "1956";
        int array[] = new int[4];

        array[0] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(0)+"");
        array[1] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(1)+"");
        array[2] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(2)+"");
        array[3] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(3)+"");
```

Obviously loops can do this, but you really didn't tell us the context of your situation